# Is this usage of STDClass a valid OOP technique in PHP?

Tags: php, oop

Please pardon me if you don't consider this a real question but I really hope that this will help other PHP coders too. So my concern is about the `STDClass` in PHP. Consider the `get()` method in below class where I'm returning a `STDClass` instance that contains information about a user.

`

```
class Bio {

    private $_name, $_age, $_add;

    public function setName($name) {

        $this->_name = $name;

    }

    public function setAge($age) {

        $this->_age = $age;

    }

    public function setAddress($address) {

        $this->_add = $address;

    }

    public function get() {

        $bio = new STDClass();

        $bio->name = $this->_name;

        $bio->age = $this->_age;

        $bio->address = $this->_add;

        return $bio;

    }

}

$bio = new Bio();

$bio->setName('Rehmat');

echo $bio->get()->name;`
```

Now my question is, is this usage of `STDClass` valid and a good way to go? Please correct me if this kind of usage has any drawbacks.

Comment: It makes no sense to do it this way. Just have your `setName` etc. execute `$this->name`, and do `echo $bio->name`.

Comment: You might as well just create public properties.

Comment: @ceejayoz Thanks for the helpful comment.

Comment: @PeeHaa Thanks, so it means that my `get()` method is valid too, please correct me if this isn't valid.

Comment: You can easily get an answer by asking yourself - does this "technique" help you in any way to make your code more readable, maintainable, simpler and easier to understand without writing documentation? What do you achieve by using `stdclass` there?

Comment: @N.B. In that case, yes it does help me a lot in several circumstances. If there isn't any drawback, then I've already got my answer

Comment: Valid (as in it will run) but utterly useless @rehmat. Contrary to popular belief OOP isn't just about wrapping data in some (fake and stupid) object.

Comment: It's not uncommon that methods return an object, but returning stdclass is almost no different from returning an array - there's no concrete implementation (you can have arbitrary properties) so the receiver still doesn't know what it gets, which means you still have to go back to your method, read what it does so you know which properties you can access. It's pretty useless in real world.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get

Comment: @Sammitch what does that URL have to do with anything?

Comment: @PeeHaa This technique is really helping me in a scenario where `JOIN` fails for MySQL queries from two separate tables as well as it is more friendly than returning an array. I was just concerning about its technical drawbacks.

Comment: It's hardly more friendly than an array, the difference is that you don't use `['']` to access a value but `->`, other than that - there's absolutely no benefit to use `StdClass` there. Why don't you create a nice class that encapsulates these properties and return that? That makes way more sense than returning a random `StdClass` object. However, since this is your code and you can do what you like - I wish you the best of luck, but from what you wrote - there's a deep problem lying somewhere in your logic, but that should be a subject for some other question :)

Comment: I think you are looking for somebody telling you "it is fine what you are doing" instead of everybody telling you it's godawful. As such this cannot be answered imo.

Comment: It's pretty much pointless doing like that. It involves two work which is creating an instance of `Bio` and accessing `get` method which returns object of `stdClass` and accessing the properties through that rather than accessing directly through the `getters` of `Bio` instance. You can have simple getters and setters in `Bio` class to do that way. Because it's like you're choosing a indirect path rather than direct path. Use getters and setters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Bio
{
    public function __construct($name, age, address)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->age = $age;
        $this->address = $address;
    }
}
```

and the rest of your methods.

```
$bio = new Bio('Some name', 24, 'Some Address');
$bio->getName();
```

Your code is valid but you don't need to make use of StdClass just to get an instance of a class. Not that it's invalid, but it's just weird to use it that way. By getting an instance of Bio as shown above you also can type check the instance type of an object, and testing and so on..
   And considering your setter methods like setAge() and setName(). If you are not doing any kind of data manipulation like making the passed name uppercase or capital case:

```
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = ucfirst($name);
}
```

If you are not doing such operations then I think it's not worth creating them just for the sake of getters and setters.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, the real scenario is different and `STDClass` is really helping me a lot. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: That's the point, STDClass should not be of any help to you. Never will you encounter any usage of STDClass in actuall projects except for may be testing. But just to get an instance of an object usage of StdClass is not justified.  Especially when the language provides you with means of instantiation of classes. Why don't you use constructor() ?

Comment: @rehmat If your stdClass approach is helping you, you're doing something **else** wrong as well.

Comment: @ceejayoz Thank you! That's what I want to hear back. If this isn't correct, then I'm going to reconsider my logic to find the second error that's forcing me to use the `STDClass`

Comment: @rehmat Sounds good. You should consider a new question with specific details about the obstacle you're encountering. Maybe we can help. Also consider taking a look at how Laravel's Eloquent/Fluent systems interact with the database and handle properties like this.

Comment: @ceejayoz Thank you for being so helpful. I'm going to have a look over the resource you suggested.